# MEF : Use Export and Import from other project

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism, mef, silverlight-5.0

I am using MEF in my silverlight project to download Xap file of other project on a button click.

But I have to give reference of that project in my current project and after that when I run my project it includes dll file of my other project in my current xap file and then I can use export and import of other project in my current project.

But I dont want dll of other project in my curent xap file and when I click ok button then after I want to download xap file of other and want to use Import and export without giving reference of other project.

I can download other project's xap file on button click event but i can not use Export and Import which i did in other project if I did not give reference.

Without giving reference can I use import and export of other project?

If yes then how can I do this?

I used below code to download xap file of other project it works

```
   PackageCatalog cat = new PackageCatalog();
   var catalog = new PackageCatalog();
        catalog.AddPackage(Package.Current);
        Package.DownloadPackageAsync(new Uri("Test.xap", UriKind.Relative),
      (args, p) => cat.AddPackage(p));
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
```

Thanks,
HItesh